# Picture box causes form load to freeze

Tags: vb.net

I have created a VB.Net form that allows users to login to the system. In the form there is an image included inside of a picturebox, two labels & two textboxes. I have also set the form background color to light blue. Whenever I run the application the picturebox loads up first & the textboxes and the label appears after about a 2 second delay. This only happens when I set the window state to maximized, if its set to normal there is no issue. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Is .Image fixed or loaded at runtime? Which .SizeMode are you using?

Comment: Its a fixed image, I have set it via the designer. Size mode is set to stretch.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to let your code compile during the Shown section, rather then the Load part.
If that doesn't work, can you please give us the code that you are using, perhaps there is something strange in there.

Comment: There is no code. Everything including the source of the image is added via the designer the problem only occurs when the window state is set to maximized. There is no code in the form load event either so that can't be a reason.